# Deploy Python Flask Docker Heroku - "Non UTF-8 code" error blows up Release phase

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, heroku

This little container runs famously when deployed manually via Heroku CLI. It's only when I try to have Github do it that this error shows up in the Release phase:

```
2021-05-28T17:17:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-05-28T17:17:39.901704+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c 'if curl $HEROKU_RELEASE_LOG_STREAM --silent --connect-timeout 10 --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 >/tmp/log-stream; then
2021-05-28T17:17:39.901704+00:00 app[api]: chmod u+x /tmp/log-stream
2021-05-28T17:17:39.901704+00:00 app[api]: /tmp/log-stream /bin/sh -c '"'"'app.py'"'"'
2021-05-28T17:17:39.901704+00:00 app[api]: else
2021-05-28T17:17:39.901704+00:00 app[api]: app.py
2021-05-28T17:17:39.901704+00:00 app[api]: fi'` by user charlesdwright@gmail.com
2021-05-28T17:17:56.070039+00:00 heroku[release.1657]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c 'if curl https://heroku-release-output.s3.amazonaws.com/log-stream?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJ3LIQ2SWG7V76SVQ%2F20210528%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210528T171739Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=3ee907467ee7082624e2521c3a9b2abd5dc10b05bb0e90386e48a1064fef375e --silent --connect-timeout 10 --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 >/tmp/log-stream; then
2021-05-28T17:17:56.703967+00:00 heroku[release.1657]: State changed from starting to up
2021-05-28T17:17:58.397549+00:00 heroku[release.1657]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-28T17:17:58.482629+00:00 heroku[release.1657]: State changed from up to complete
2021-05-28T17:17:58.335854+00:00 app[release.1657]: File "/bin/sh", line 1
2021-05-28T17:17:58.335867+00:00 app[release.1657]: SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x9c' in file /bin/sh on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
2021-05-28T17:17:59.747839+00:00 app[api]: Release v29 command failed by user blah@yadda.com
```

1. Have searched the code for `fi'` and found nothing.
2. Have rectified every warning that Intellij throws on the code.
3. Have added this: `#coding=utf-8` to .py files.
4. Have combed Stackoverflow and the Web in general.

Not sure where the /bin/sh file referenced in the log is (it does not reside in the container), seems to be a Heroku thing.  But of course when I attempt to open a ticket there, they refer me here because it's a free app.

Thanks in advance for any clues.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that all your files are complete especially the procfile and the requirements.txt file, and also check the syntax among your HTML and python files.